# The meaning of Let us not or Do not let us

Tags: meaning, grammar, verbs, word-usage, negation

As far as I know, the negatives of *Let us* are *Let us not* and *Do not let us*. And *Let us* has two different meaning: one is a suggestion and the other is an imperative. Then doesn't Let us not or Do not let us have the two different meaning?

a. Let us not watch the movie.
b. Do not let us watch the movie.

I think both a and b are correct and have the same meaning: one is *How about we don't watch the movie?*(suggestion) and the other is *You shouldn't allow us to watch the movie*(imperative). Am I right?

Comment: If you say "Don't let's watch the movie" then this would be taken as a suggestion.  But "Do not let us..." would normally be taken as a directive.

Comment: @Pax - and not only that, A would be said by people in the set of “us” to others in the set. B would be said to someone outside the group.

Comment: @Jim Agreed.  What the OP describes as a "suggestion" is actually a let-imperative, in CaGEL's terminology.  And the subject of the let-imperative "let us" is first person, as you point out.  It is possible to read a let-imperative as a non-let imperative unless it is in the form "let's".  The non-let imperative "let us watch" has an implied second-person subject.

Comment: In the norml course, let's not is suggestive; don't let us is imperative

Comment: "Let  us not" and "let's not" have different connotations to me.  "Let us not" is more of a cry for help than a suggestion.